# Eyeota redirect

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

In my blogger blog page speed score  i see many redirects involving eyeota.

```
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

http://aa.agkn.com/adscores/g.pixel?sid=9202273308&_redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dc9gd69u%26uid%3D
http://d.agkn.com/pixel/1716/?che=1481792156&sk=164680802175000292833&as2=&ey=&lws=&rtk=&mm=&l1=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dc9gd69u%26uid%3D164680802175000292833
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=c9gd69u&uid=164680802175000292833
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://dmp.adform.net/serving/cookie/match/?party=1009
http://dmp.adform.net/serving/cookie/match/?CC=1&party=1009
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=7799324865709062041&bid=9gdtmu1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://dpm.demdex.net/ibs:dpid=30064&dpuuid=15901b1d84d-556d000001091f07&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D6j5b2cv%26uid%3D%24%7BDD_UUID%7D
http://dpm.demdex.net/demconf.jpg?et:ibs%7cdata:dpid=30064&dpuuid=15901b1d84d-556d000001091f07&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D6j5b2cv%26uid%3D%24%7BDD_UUID%7D
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=6j5b2cv&uid=31021475785568601412848670218103704009
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://eyeota-sync.dotomi.com/eyeota/match?nuid=2Tys-SGs5avUG5p265VZztx3k5YI6J0eQDJs1bjS3cFA&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dr8d1b20
http://eyeota-sync.dotomi.com/eyeota/match?dtm_test=24a568617960570&nuid=2Tys-SGs5avUG5p265VZztx3k5YI6J0eQDJs1bjS3cFA&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dr8d1b20
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=r8d1b20
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://ib.adnxs.com/getuid?http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fuid%3D%24UID%26bid%3D2cr76e1
http://ib.adnxs.com/bounce?%2Fgetuid%3Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fps.eyeota.net%252Fmatch%253Fuid%253D%2524UID%2526bid%253D2cr76e1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=6005158385834267502&bid=2cr76e1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://idsync.rlcdn.com/423476.gif?partner_uid=2XeFxksSmudS0jcz9XjZedJrFx8yYIfSN9cZlgpLcq3s
http://idsync.rlcdn.com/423476.gif?partner_uid=2XeFxksSmudS0jcz9XjZedJrFx8yYIfSN9cZlgpLcq3s&redirect=1
http://dpm.demdex.net/ibs:dpid=477&dpuuid=a638832221526b35d0e0e3531f9a73603dfdcaf2f42485c9276f15e29b80d097b0da87c991749652&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fidsync.rlcdn.com%2F362248.gif%3Fpartner_uid%3D%24%7BDD_UUID%7D
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=eyeota&ttd_tpi=1
http://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmb/generic?ttd_pid=eyeota&ttd_tpi=1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=1d382519-ddab-44ba-af6d-b7b6002a233e&bid=1e2n4ou
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://ml314.com/utsync.ashx?eid=50052&et=0&fp=2kPFVUhlA6HSQT0QIsBHTlaR4UCNxTvzANmeCdFLWHPU&return=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dr8hrb20%26uid%3Dnil
http://ml314.com/utsync.ashx?hop=1&eid=50052&et=0&fp=2kPFVUhlA6HSQT0QIsBHTlaR4UCNxTvzANmeCdFLWHPU&return=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3Dr8hrb20%26uid%3Dnil
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=r8hrb20&uid=nil
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://pix04.revsci.net/J13421/a3/0/3/match.302?matchId=eyeota
http://pix04.revsci.net/J13421/a3/Z/3/match.302?matchId=eyeota&asidi=dFgHnCMBQo1dFH8--6aALw
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=c9gd6h0&uid=BMyOVavVFBvusnP-cYWSe8cLC-qJ
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://pixel.tapad.com/idsync/ex/receive?partner_id=2376&partner_device_id=2HoThDeec77FDgP3xnNxMa-pqVr27cTG51quYxRFwHE0&partner_url=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fuid%3D%24%7BTA_DEVICE_ID%7D%26bid%3D6bnoi0v
http://pixel.tapad.com/idsync/ex/receive/check?partner_id=2376&partner_device_id=2HoThDeec77FDgP3xnNxMa-pqVr27cTG51quYxRFwHE0&partner_url=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fuid%3D%24%7BTA_DEVICE_ID%7D%26bid%3D6bnoi0v
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=4a751131-c2a4-11e6-ae96-005056a24b29&bid=6bnoi0v
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://rs.gwallet.com/r1/pixel/x31662
http://rp.gwallet.com/r1/cm/p58
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=cjukc90&uid=AB-doMnHq3HOTo7mFK1luqSrQ
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://sync.adap.tv/eyeota_user_sync
http://sync.adaptv.advertising.com/eyeota_user_sync?
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=6bib2cv&uid=EUX8657954873858456062
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10015&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D7vi0rg0%26uid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D
http://sync.mathtag.com/sync/img?mt_exid=10015&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D7vi0rg0%26uid%3D%5BMM_UUID%5D&mm_bnc&mm_bct
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=7vi0rg0&uid=7c765852-5a9b-4900-bcde-76ce60ce3b0b
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/29539?limit=1&id=2nYW97aJ1m2qhHeZ5_rsiVJYiGYYdy9SbUYyZnquWEEs
http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=bluekai&google_cm&google_sc
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/2981?id=&google_gid=CAESEO0lHbp8cb1zqp5-4wIAJi0&google_cver=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/35702?id=c4983554-15fe-4495-9786-334b26deb66f&redir=%2F%2Ftrc.taboola.com%2Fsg%2Fbluekai%2F1%2Fcm%3Ftaboola_hm%3D%24_BK_UUID
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/35702?dt=0&r=35313916&sig=2433486270&bkca=KJy+iLLvQY9DHnds5QqoNUnHJiv/N3laP0DjQ+Ud5h4OpcOZZmCfObgMxQO+hORGQOJD+jtA7/Bk6Qzg8PSPTswoYj+xElcNRtpm05xrUfMzmTjBqpCBHsgxfiJXIkdbye/uO7oR2ngmTy4/ZunQ
http://trc.taboola.com/sg/bluekai/1/cm?taboola_hm=sgaq5Q9999er6PJR
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=7&c2=13739933&c3=20121515121&ns__t=1481792148732&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=1FAKT%20-%20Teste%20Psikologjike%20e%20Kuize%20Logjike&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.1fakt.com%2F&c9=
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b2?c1=7&c2=13739933&c3=20121515121&ns__t=1481792148732&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=1FAKT%20-%20Teste%20Psikologjike%20e%20Kuize%20Logjike&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.1fakt.com%2F&c9=
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://cm.g.doubleclick.net/pixel?google_nid=eye&google_cm&google_sc&bid=gdo9o51&newuser=1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=gdo9o51&newuser=1&google_gid=CAESECysUlLAUzTpo5NAjzOBj0c&google_cver=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://d.turn.com/r/dd/id/L2NzaWQvMS9jaWQvMjg0NTA1NDYvdC8w/url/http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=1mpjpn0&turn_id=$!{TURN_UUID}&newuser=1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=1mpjpn0&turn_id=7683654067838815416&newuser=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://i.w55c.net/ping_match.gif?st=EYEOTA&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D9sn4omv%26uid%3D_wfivefivec_%26newuser%3D1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=9sn4omv&uid=PS8e8z2t1ChrPt5&newuser=1
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://p.rfihub.com/cm?pub=24472&in=1
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=639300049355347303&bid=omt9pi0
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://ps.eyeota.net/pixel?pid=c4b2cjv&t=iframe&sid=LIMK&pubID=1614&cat=Arts%20and%20Entertainment
http://ps.eyeota.net/pixel/bounce/?pid=c4b2cjv&t=iframe&sid=LIMK&pubID=1614&cat=Arts%20and%20Entertainment
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://rtd.tubemogul.com/upi/pid/lons7jax?puid=15901b1d84d-556d000001091f07&redir=http%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fuid%3D%24%7BTM_USER_ID%7D%26bid%3D0rijhbu
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?uid=5964300853909240290&bid=0rijhbu
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://sp.adbrn.com/match?syncid=eyeota1_970fc36f-6bf6-4f5f-bc53-e726d28b9c05&cid=2BDJ8anndKmSMa7lAwE6CEx7B9BrbDQYq36qYHpqEgS4&rurl=https%3A%2F%2Fps.eyeota.net%2Fmatch%3Fbid%3D162m4ou%26adbrain_cookie_id%3D%24%7BCOOKIE_ID%7D
https://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=162m4ou&adbrain_cookie_id=e354b9ab-f489-74da-6787-bc0088be9303
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://sync.tidaltv.com/GenericUserSync.ashx?dpid=42
http://ps.eyeota.net/match?bid=2crn9e1&uid=dbb4b7f6-3bda-4a42-b4b8-5151a41b962c
```

They are slowing considerably my website. I never used eyeota but i'm using limk and taboola. My questions are:
- Are limk and / or taboola related to eyeota?
- If not how can i remove all redirects related to eyeota?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I deleted the **histats.com** codes from my website and everything went right

Comment: Look at the OP's comment on the other answer that is over 2 weeks old. He is not using histats.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Do you use histats.com for the statistics? I resolved when I removed the script of histats.

Comment: Thank you for asking. No, i don't use histats. I use limk, taboola and google analytics.

Answer (score 1):

It was limk.com . I removed limk.com and the result is as follows

```
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

http://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmf/generic?ttd_pid=054f32o&ttd_tpi=1
http://match.adsrvr.org/track/cmb/generic?ttd_pid=054f32o&ttd_tpi=1
http://trc.taboola.com/sg/thetradedesk-network/1/rtb-h/?taboola_hm=82b438e4-2d31-4b5c-b4bf-bbd8770e6d90
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/35702?id=1afcdaad-1cc4-4c63-80ad-e0b6bec0a878&redir=%2F%2Ftrc.taboola.com%2Fsg%2Fbluekai%2F1%2Fcm%3Ftaboola_hm%3D%24_BK_UUID
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/35702?dt=0&r=1752771055&sig=2015699803&bkca=KJy+iLWvQY9xHndsqGSVZJzrWDa62ipgSiDPQ+Ud+T5QjoQlE932CODexm9uDUsarrPsWWqC+RXGycuZvMsA6gBZ/M6aby5Xpi4DZY2SfGlY7tXX/asEjnhRmd6F+hm1gaarVJ0NXdQOKVTAMx==
http://trc.taboola.com/sg/bluekai/1/cm?taboola_hm=if6be99999OsUU%2BR
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=7&c2=13739933&c3=20121515121&ns__t=1484510766839&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=1FAKT%20-%20Teste%20Psikologjike%20e%20Kuize%20Logjike&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.1fakt.com%2F&c9=
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b2?c1=7&c2=13739933&c3=20121515121&ns__t=1484510766839&ns_c=UTF-8&cv=3.1&c8=1FAKT%20-%20Teste%20Psikologjike%20e%20Kuize%20Logjike&c7=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.1fakt.com%2F&c9=
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
http://tags.bluekai.com/site/35702?dt=0&r=1243908029&sig=2015699803&bkca=KJy+iLWvQY9xHndsqGSVZJzrWDa62ipgSiDPQ+Ud+T5QjoQlE932CODexm9uDUsarrPsWWqC+RXGycuZvMsA6gBZ/M6aby5Xpi4DZY2SfGlY7tXX/asEjnhRmd6F+hm1gaarVJ0NXdQOKVTAMx==
http://trc.taboola.com/sg/bluekai/1/cm?taboola_hm=if6be99999OsUU%2BR
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7585/is3by3adg7x1y5k6g.jpg
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/7585/is3by3adg7x1y5k6g.jpg?size_id=5
```

Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

```
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/b604/55mqe2d586a539y6g.jpg
https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/b604/55mqe2d586a539y6g.jpg?size_id=3
```

This helpet reduce loading time by at least 5%.

Answer (score 1):

The widely used [ShareThis](https://sharethis.com/) button toolbars also add this cookie so removing that from your site may help others resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was solved by removing the script he used to whos.amung.us statistics also some people ShareThis eliminating the problem was solved.